# Dygraph using unix times displays nothing

Tags: dygraphs

Please help me with my first attempt at dygraphs. I have the following code that does not produce a graph. What have I done wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/52Qv4/1/

```
  g = new Dygraph(

  // containing div
  document.getElementById("graphdiv"), [
      [1396411199, 50, 10],
      [1396497599, 63, 11],
      [1396583999, 120, 12],
      [1396670399, 55, 20],
      [1396756799, 60, 22],
      [1396843199, 63, 25],
      [1396929599, 52, 25]
  ],
  // options
  {
      xRangePad: 10,
      yRangePad: 10,
      xValueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
      xValueParser: function (x) {
          return parseInt(x, 10);
      },
      xTicker: Dygraph.dateTicker,
      labels: ["Dates", "Not Kept", "Hosts"],
      title: "Promises not kept",
      legend: "always",
      drawPoints: "true",
      pointSize: 2,
      colors: ["orange", "blue", "black"],
      strokeWidth: 0
  });
```

Comment: Your fiddle fails because it's not including the dygraphs JavaScript. Use dygraphs.com/fiddle as a template to fix this. Additionally, you'll want to use millis since epoch, not seconds since epoch. You should open the console and follow the advice it gives you -- you're using a number of deprecated options.

Comment: Updated the fiddle, but the results are still the same. I can't see how to work the console is jsfiddle. I do have a copy locally and the console shows the error: 'TypeError: s.toExponential is not a function' http://jsfiddle.net/52Qv4/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Dygraphs docs: http://dygraphs.com/data.html. It states:

> xValueParser affects CSV only

Updating your code to use CSV works:

```
  g = new Dygraph(

  // containing div
  document.getElementById("graphdiv"), 
             "Date,Series1,Series2\n" +
              "1247382000,50,20\n" +
              "1247986800,50,10\n",
  // options
  {
      xRangePad: 10,
      yRangePad: 10,
      xValueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
      xValueParser: function (x) {
          return 1000 * parseInt(x, 10);
      },
      xTicker: Dygraph.dateTicker,
      labels: ["Dates", "Not Kept", "Hosts"],
      title: "Promises not kept",
      legend: "always",
      drawPoints: "true",
      pointSize: 2,
      colors: ["orange", "blue", "black"],
      strokeWidth: 1
  });
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/52Qv4/6/)**